# Adding to an Inventory file in Ansible

Tags: ansible-2.x

I am creating the Amazon VPC Subnet using ansible module. It is creating successfully.

But i want to store my created subnet id and subnet name in the inventory file under one group name called [epic_xuk]

Please let us know how to do this in Ansible.

Regards
Arun

Comment: Ansible is designed to be idempotent, so it's not the best way (though I'm sure it's possible).  However, why not just use the [ec2_vpc_net_facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_net_facts_module.html) module and store the subnet id/name as facts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `lineinfile` module:

```
---
- name: Creating an AWS VPC inside mentioned Region
  ec2_vpc:
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    state:  present
    cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-vpc", "Environment":"{{ ENVIRONMENT }}" }
    subnets: "{{ vpc_subnets }}" 
    internet_gateway: yes
  register: vpc

- name: Write public and private subnets ids to inventory file
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/path-to-your-inventory-file"
    regexp: "^{{ item.resource_tags.Alias  }}"
    line: "{{ item.resource_tags.Alias }}: {{  item.id  }}"
  with_items: "{{ vpc.subnets }}"
```

For detail instructions, you can consult this [ansible repo](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles/blob/master/roles/vpc/tasks/main.yml)
Hope that might help you.